# Timeseries Charts data every 5 Seconds?? Worried about Performance 

Tags: performance, charts

We have Time Series data for every 5 Seconds . 
Now you can assume what will be the Data for a single day ??

We have a requirement of showing a graph/ chart for a Whole Month .

(For example a user selects a Month  from Jan 1st 2011 to Jan 31st 2011 )
The data  loaded might be too heavy and it may degrade the applications performance or make it Out of Memory .

How can we handle this requirement ??

The Flotr API uses this method to draw the Charts , which requires the data to be already loaded .

```
summaryGraph: function (data, bounds) {
var p = Flotr.draw(
 $('summaryGraph'),
[data],
{

}
)
}
```

please suggest any inputs for this .Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

OK you have time series data collected every 5 seconds.  That leads to about 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 / 5 = 518400 observations.  Why not bin the time series data together, i.e. use a higher aggregation than 5 seconds?  I assume you do not actually need 5 second precision on your x axis, or you'd be talking about hundreds of thousands of pixels wide charts.

What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Clients don't compromise , i think he has to show the data . I think DOJO provides a good solution using

which will e responsible to pint out to the URL of the servlet .

Not sure , experts may add more to this .

Comment: Please provide any  ideas on this ??